# Best method for a Json API GET request handler

Tags: php, curl, fopen, file-get-contents, fsockopen

This question may be a little vague but I'd like to hear peoples' opinions on the subject, from their experiences.

I'm using a RESTful API which returns a json string, this could potentially receive hundreds of hits a second.

Now my question is, which is the best method to handle a high volume of requests?

I've done a benchmark test for `file_get_contents` and `curl`, based on 50 requests each and I've found curl to range from anywhere between 0.06s and 0.07s per request, whereas file_get_contents ranges from 0.159s to 0.18s per request.

So from a very basic test it looks like curl would be the best option, but then you have other methods, plus many variables which could effect the results, especially when you're talking about hundreds of requests hitting the server every second.

I don't need the whole functionality of curl, the error handlers are great, but I'll only ever be dealing with simple GET requests, so would it be worthwhile using something else, like `fopen`?